# Динамическое создание input

Tags: javascript, html

Есть функция:

```
$("input[name='file_img[]']").change(function () {
        var max = 5;
        var total = $("input[name='file_img[]']").length;
        if (total < max) {
            total = total + 1;
            $("#gallery").append('<input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_img[]">');
        }
    });
```

по идеи как видно из кода она должна срабатывать 4 раза т.е. чтобы было 5 input`ов, но она срабатывает всего один раз. Помогите. Она не должна быть цыклом. Она должна срабатывать только при нажатии.

Comment: так у вас стоит проверка, если, а не цыкл "пока меньше 5-ти должно делаться то-то"

Comment: так она и не должна быть цыклом она должна срабатывать при нажатии на input

Comment: как минимум, переменная total должна быть глобальной, иначе она у вас не увеличивается на 1 как вы хотите, а при каждом вызове change() снова равняется $("input[name='file_img[]']").length

Comment: @humster_spb не нужно делать переменную `total` глобальной. Достаточно убрать бесполезную строку `total = total + 1;`.

Comment: она один фиг отрабатывает только один раз даже если total сделать глобальной; даже если строку убрать серавно только один раз отрабатывает

Comment: а нужно чтобы сразу несколько инпутов по одному изменению добавлялись?

Comment: @Regent, она потому и бесполезна сейчас, что переменная локальная. А если сделать её глобальной, то значение будет увеличиваться.

Comment: @humster_spb зачем её хранить глобально и увеличивать, если достаточно её каждый раз высчитывать с помощью `$("input[name='file_img[]']").length`? Зачем дублировать знание о количестве input-ов? Чтобы потом удалить где-то input, забыть при этом уменьшить значение глобальной переменной и тем самым поломать всю логику?

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю, идея в том, что если выбрал файл, то появляется возможность выбрать следующий файл, и так вплоть до 5 штук. При этом у автора баг как с обработкой динамически добавленных input-ов, так и с добавлением нового input-а при смене значения любого из предыдущих input-ов, а не только последнего.

Comment: @Regent всм баг с обработкой динамически добавленных input-ов, так и с добавлением нового input-а ??

Comment: @Moonwolf45 в прямом смысле.

Comment: обработчик change Будет срабатывать только для тех элементов, которые уже были добавлены. Для новых ты в этот обработчик не зайдешь. Возможно в этом и есть твоя настоящая проблема

Comment: Ну и какой тогда мне обработчик вешать??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В js есть такое понятие как "делегирование событий". На динамически добавляемые элементы нельзя напрямую повесить обработчик. Но можно повесить на родителя:

```js
$('body').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if($('input').size() < 5) {
       $('body').append('<input type="file" /><br />');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" /><br />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```